# Fetch first element in 'new array' JSONP response with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, jsonp

I try to keep it simple:

**Problem:** how to fetch the first element (weight here) from the new Array with JQuery

**Current JQuery:**

```
function xyz() 
{
            var the_url = 'http://longurl'+encodeURIComponent(searchBox.val());

            var x1 = $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: the_url,
                   dataType: "script"
            });
}

callback_function = function(suggestions)
{
    return suggestions[0];
}
```

**JSONP response**:

```
callback_function("w", new Array("weight", "weight loss", "wound"), 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That response isn't JSONP, but may work (never tried the approach), your callback should be looking for the *second* parameter though, like this:

```
callback_function = function(something, suggestions, somethingElse)
{
  return suggestions[0];
}
```